# Does LINQ allow simplifying this construction?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list `List<string> MyValues = new List<string>{};` . In my program I need to hard-code the following:

```
MyValues.Add(MyFunc(1)); MyValues.Add(MyFunc(2)); ... MyValues.Add(MyFunc(20));
```

Definitely, I can do it in a for-loop. But I guess there should be a LINQ construction that allows filling a list with one simple construction substituting this loop.

Could anybody suggest such a LINQ construction that would fill my list?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Although it's possible, I don't think it's simpler than a `for` loop. If you want to make your code as easy to understand as possible, I wouldn't recommend any LINQ helper functions here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simplify this using [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
List<string> myValues = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(MyFunc).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx) to generate all the numbers, along with `Select` to do the transform; and use `AddRange` to add all the elements to your list.

```
MyValues.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(i => MyFunc(i)));
```